# How to find files last modified date?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am reading several files as `StorageFile` and it doesn't seem to have a LastModified property. Is it possible to find somewhere this information or is it gone completely?

Answer (score 8):

Found it!
Now you have to go via `BasicProperties` for properties like LastAccessDate

Here is the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.aspx)